# R: Find length matches and aggregate values

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, aggregate, pivot-table

Assume we have a data table that has following structure:

http://pastebin.com/7Nj0ix75

*time_days* and *deadline_sub_launched* were manually inserted via Excel to count the number of days for each project. Note: The original list ist much longer and has more variation in project duration.

What I want to do is to find all projects with an equal runtime and aggregate their row values. So $runs for all projects with 5 days should be aggregated, $runs for all projects with 3 days should be aggregated etc.

Projects with length 5 should be

```
runs.l5
113 (sum of row1 of projects length 5)
210 (sum of row2 of projects length 5)
178 (sum of row3 of projects length 5)
129 (sum of row4 of projects length 5)
197 (sum of row5 of projects length 5)
```

It would also be good -for control- to have an additional list that shows which projects sort into which #days bucket.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package, we can do:

```
df %>% group_by(time_days) %>%
  summarize(total_runs = sum(runs))
```

This should give you the total runs for each sub-group of duration in days. You can do operations on the other columns within the summarize function as well, but that depends on how exactly you want to aggregate the start/end dates and deadlines.

Comment: I think I did a mistake in my explanation. I want to see each the aggregate value of day1, day2, day3, day4 for projects with a duration of 5 days. In my aggregate, I don't want to summarize across all rows of all projects.